# Using strings result in mysqli_fetch_array one by one (PHP)

Tags: php, html

I am trying to build a performance appraisal program where every employee should submit score for their team member. So when an employee sign in to their account, their panel should show:

- the name of the team member they should assess (4 friends),
- 9 questions for each team member they should assess.

I can't  separate the team member's name for each set of questions.

```
$MenilaiRekan1=mysqli_query($conn, "select NAMA from user where UNIT='$Unit2' AND CABANG='$Cabang2' and JABATAN='$Jabatan2' and NAMA<>'$Nama2'");

if (mysqli_num_rows($MenilaiRekan1)>0) {

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($MenilaiRekan1))
{
    $NamaRekan=array($row['NAMA']);
    }
}else{
    echo "O results";
}

echo $NamaRekan[0];
```

Comment: Replace `$NamaRekan=array($row['NAMA']);` -> `$NamaRekan[] = $row['NAMA'];`

Comment: works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_push()` to add value to empty array

```
$MenilaiRekan1=mysqli_query($conn, "select NAMA from user where UNIT='$Unit2' AND CABANG='$Cabang2' and JABATAN='$Jabatan2' and NAMA<>'$Nama2'");

 if (mysqli_num_rows($MenilaiRekan1)>0) {
    $NamaRekan = array();
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($MenilaiRekan1))
    {
        array_push($NamaRekan, row['NAMA']);
        }
    }else{
        echo "O results";
    }

    echo $NamaRekan[0];
```

Comment: Why?  Just `$NamaRekan[] = $row['NAMA'];`

Comment: I'm quite sure it's the same. My above answer is just my habit of using it :)

Comment: And u r right, using `$NamaRekan[] = $row['NAMA'];` is faster